# Bounds for Dirichlet $L$-functions on the critical line

Tags: analytic-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, l-functions

I am interested in bounds on the constants $A,B$ such that
$$L\big(\tfrac{1}{2}+it,\chi\big)\ll_\varepsilon q^{A+\varepsilon}(|t|+1)^{B+\varepsilon},$$
and was curious if any developments have been made since the work of Huxley and Watt in 2000.  In particular, I am interested in fixed-order Dirichlet characters $\chi\bmod{q}$, though any bound applying to general Dirichlet characters would probably suffice.

Comment: The state of the art is two recent papers by Ian Petrow and Matthew P. Young, who show unconditionally that $L(1/2 + it,\chi) \ll_{\varepsilon} q^{1/6 + \varepsilon} (|t| + 1)^{1/6 + \varepsilon}$.